# C# Gerar numero aleatório e único, verificar no banco se já foi gerado algum número igual e caso tenha voltar a gerar outro numero

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde preciso **gerar** um **número aleatório** e **único** e gravar no banco, esse sistema irá rodar todo dia gerando novos números com base em regras de negócio.

Com ajuda dos colegas nos comentários modifiquei meu código, colocando agora no banco a coluna "cupom" como única, assim quando tentar gravar nunca irá permitir se já existir um valor igual no banco.

Meu problema agora e que quando acontece de já existir um número igual ao que foi gerado, meu sistema gera um erro de gravação e não consigo fazer com que gere um novo número para tentar gravar novamente.

Preciso que quando não conseguir gravar por o número já existir ele entre em "loop", gerando um novo cupom até que esse não esteja no banco e possa continuar a execução.

Para gerar o número aleatório:

```
 public string CupomCampanha()
        {
              string numeroAleatorio = "";
              var random = new Random();
              var possibilidades = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
              var resultado = possibilidades.OrderBy(number => random.Next()).Take(10).ToArray();
              return numeroAleatorio = String.Join("", resultado);
        }
```

Para fazer o insert no banco

```
public void InserirIndicacaoContas(string cpf)
        {
              if (cpf != "-")
              {
                    var conexao = AbrirConexao();
                    var comando = conexao.CreateCommand();

                    comando.CommandText =
                    $"INSERT INTO campanhaCupons (cpf, cupon, idProduto, dataImportacao) VALUES (@cpf, @cupon, @idProduto, @dataImportacao)";
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("cpf", cpf);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("cupon", _geraCupon.CupomCampanha());
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("idProduto", "1");
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("dataImportacao", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

                    ExecutaComando(comando);
              }
```

Espero ter conseguido explicar melhor agora.

Comment: Por ter se estendido nos comentários, a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117897/discussion-on-question-by-joao-c-gerar-numero-aleatorio-e-unico-verificar-no-b) e pode prosseguir lá pelo link fornecido

Comment: As perguntas aqui precisam explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhadas de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Além disso, pelo enunciado da pergunta, provavelmente se trata de um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70), vale à pena uma lida no link.

Comment: Revertido. Não modifique o escopo as perguntas depois de aceitas. Se quiser modificar primeiro tire a aceitação ou faça uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como disse nos comentários :

- O número do cupom você sempre terá que criar, aleatoriamente como especificou, porém fazendo a coluna da tabela ter a restrição [`UNIQUE`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) o próprio DB o impede de adicionar um número do cupom duplicado assim poupando o tempo de programar uma pesquiza por duplicidade no banco de dados.
- Quando tenta duplicar um registro num coluna `UNIQUE` é gerada uma exceção. Use essa exceção a seu favor coloque o código num [loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) dentro dum [tratamento de exceções](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch), se der erro reitere o loop e gere outro número de cupom senão der erro é que o cupom foi salvo e abandone o loop.

Aplicado no exemplo:

```
while (true){
  var comando = conexao.CreateCommand();      //Cria um novo comando sql.
  comando.CommandText =
  $"INSERT INTO campanhaCupons (cpf, cupon, idProduto, dataImportacao) VALUES (@cpf, @cupon, @idProduto, @dataImportacao)";
  comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("cpf", cpf);
  comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("cupon", _geraCupon.CupomCampanha());
  //Abre um bloco de tratamento de exceções...
  try{
     ExecutaComando(comando);  //Quando não conseguir inserir registro gera uma exceção MySqlException.
  catch {
      continue;                //Se uma exceção foi gerada reitera o loop.    
  }
  break;                       //Caso nenhuma exceção tenha sido gerada abandona o loop
}
```

Comment: Teste o código antes de votar ou aceitar. Podem haver erros pois eu fiz de cabeça, não tenho como testar pois não tenho uma cópia do seu DB e não vou fazer um mock de db no ano novo.

Comment: Apesar de responder (de certa forma) a pergunta, imagine quando o pool de números estiver saturado, e você começar a ter sucessivas violações de chave, até dar sorte de pegar um número livre. Infelizmente, o pedido do autor já parte de um problema conceitual.

Comment: @AugustoVasques testei aqui mais ele não está caindo no catch quando o numero já existe no banco, do try ele já vai para o final do while e não repete o laço. Os 2 erros que recebo no console são: Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
Erro ao executar query: Duplicate entry '2960473185' for key 'campanhacupons.campanhaCupons_UN' || LINHA:    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado por toda ajuda, feliz ano novo para você e toda sua familia!

Comment: Gostaria de fazer algumas ponderações, sugerindo algumas boas práticas. Primeiro, atente-se a regra de negócio do que você pretende desenvolver. Então sim, você deve deixar a coluna que vai receber esse número como UNIQUE em sua tabela no banco de dados. Seria para ajudar na validação? NÃO! É para a modelagem ser compatível com seu negócio, em banco NÃO se usa, ou não deveria usar, regra de negócio. Segundo, uso de "exception" para regra de negócio não é correto (vejo muitos desenvolvedores usando para tal fim). O nome já diz que é uma exceção a regra. Qual regra? Nesse caso, de negócio!

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha, obrigado pelas orientações.